# How to use php file_get_contents with ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

A part of my project need to get datas from an ESP8266 with php script. I tested this script and i don't know why i can get the datas in an iframe element and nothing with file_get_content function. In iframe element my browser displayes "Hello my friend!" as wanted:

The ESP8266 server mode at 192.168.4.1 address, part of code:

```
String webpage = "<div id='div1'>Hello</div>";
webpage += "<div id='div2'>my</div>";
webpage += "<div id='div3'>friend!</div>";

String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
cipSend += 0;
cipSend += ",";
cipSend +=webpage.length();
cipSend +="\r\n";

sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);
sendData("AT+CIPCLOSE=0\r\n", 100, DEBUG);
```

The php script:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <iframe src="http://192.168.4.1/?cmd=SS,0,0,"></iframe>

 <?php

 $url="http://192.168.4.1/?cmd=SS,0,0,";
 $lines_string = file_get_contents($url);
 echo htmlspecialchars($lines_string);

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i replace the url by:

```
$url=https://arduino.stackexchange.com
```

It works with php script,so what is the issue with the ESP8266 ?

Comment: Where does the PHP run? I think your PHP is running on a remote server, while the ESP is on a local network (behind a NAT), with a local IP address. The remote server can't access your local network, while you browser can.

Comment: Php script is running on php home server Linux machine. I can send all i want to the ESP8266 by wifi.

Comment: Is your home server on the same network (/subnet)? Can you curl/gwet the url from your home server?

Comment: No home network. Just php server (localhost) and ESP8266 as access point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process the request by php, you must send valid HTTP response. The browser tolerates too much.

```
String webpage = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
webpage += "<div id='div1'>Hello</div>";
```

Comment: PERFECT !!! I can get "Hello" with

<code>
file_get_contents("http://192.168.4.1/?cmd=SS,0,0,");
</code>